What is the correct past-participle inflection of the verb ‘weightlifting’ – and why?
What is the correct past-participle inflection of the verb weightlifting, and why?

Weightlifted.
Weight-lifted.
Both (1) and (2) are valid and mean the same thing.
Either of (1) or (2), but which to use varies by context. If this case applies, please explain the contexts requiring form (1) versus those requiring form (2).
Neither (1) nor (2) but rather some other term than these two. If this case applies, please provide that other term.
Neither, and there cannot ever be one. If this case applies, please explain why there cannot be one in the first place.


Despite the existence of the verb-derived gerund weightlifting, the "base form" to weightlift doesn't exist (it's certainly not in the full Oxford English Dictionary). So it's a bit pointless asking how to "correctly" write the past participle of the "non-verb". The associated verb phrase (not "phrasal verb") is to lift weights, with past tense He lifted weights..

Sounds like an answer to me.

Someone else (not me) has closevoted "Answerable by dictionary". I'm in two minds myself, given that it's in wiktionary, thefreedictionary, and vocabulary.com (but not the OED, Collins, or Merriam-Webster). Anyway, I'm not convinced "Is this a valid word?" makes for a good ELU question. And "correct hyphenation" is even more "marginal".

@FumbleFingers Naw, it wasn't even close! As the former closure has been unclosed, you’re at liberty to provide whatever answer you please.

to weightlift exists in AmE.  I'm gonna go weightlift  is something you'd hear in the gym of an American high school during football season.  But it's not a fully-fledged verb. The past tense is far more likely to use the gerund as in did some weightlifting than weightlifted.

@TimR Again, that is not a gerund but a noun in did some weightlifting. You've confused form and function. Because gerunds are verbs, not nouns, their modifiers must be adverbs, not adjectives or other NP components.

@tchrist I'm using the word as defined in dictionaries like Cambridge and Oxford:   "a word ending in "-ing" that is made from a verb and used like a noun".  I'd say a word ending in -ing and modified by an adverb is a participle.

@TimR Insistently calling things participles no matter their use is always going to get you into trouble←Notice that calling there is modified by an adverb and takes objects as well, proving it's a verb not a noun. Verb phrases of this sort can be subjects, too, as I have just shown. Dictionaries tend to be completely clueless — read: useless — about parts of speech.

Another option - lifted is often used to mean lifted weights but with the 2nd word omitted. This would be a common usage in some contexts (e.g. "Are you doing weights this evening?" "No, I lifted this morning", which also hints at another alternative)

Weightlifting is most often a noun, and nouns don't have past participles. The corresponding verb is usually expressed not by a single word, but by the phrase "to lift weights". I haven't found any entries in a traditional dictionary for a verb weightlift, although you can see it, marked "rare", in Wiktionary.
The incorporation of an object into a word is most commonly seen in nouns or adjectives derived from verbs, not so often in verbs themselves, as I mentioned previously in relation to the adjectives spellbound and spellbinding and the noun blameshifting.
There is no editorial guideline that says to use a hyphen only in some parts of a verb, but not in other parts of the same verb. If you for some reason decide to use "to weightlift" as a verb, its past participle would be weightlifted and its gerund/present participle would be weightlifting. If you use "to weight-lift" as a verb, its past participle would be weight-lifted and its gerund/present participle would be weight-lifting.
There aren't general rules about whether compound verbs like this, or compound words in general, should be spelled with or without a hyphen. But the general trend in recent centuries has been towards less use of hyphens than in the past: "weight-lifting" itself used to be a commonly used spelling, but has now been overtaken by weightlifting. I'd therefore advising using the non-hyphenated spelling if you make use of a verb weightlift, weightlifted, etc.

By way of analogy: strawberry-picking doesn't have a past tense form strawberry-picked.

@alphabet But cherry-pick does. I think it all depends on how frequently the compound verb is used as a single verb. If it's used as frequently as cherry-pick, it shows up in most dictionaries. The verb weight-lift isn't as frequently used as the verb cherry-pick but more frequently used than the verb_strawberry-pick_.

@JK2 cherry-pick is just a case of rebracketing, probably made more acceptable by the fact that the meaning of cherry-picking is so lexicalized. (Note: the verb cherry-pick cannot be used to describe literally picking cherries!)

@alphabet The same is true for weight-lift especially among weightlifters. It cannot be used to describe literally lifting weights outside the realm of working out.

@JK2 Weight-lifting is clearly much more closely related to lifting weights than cherry-picking (in the usual sense) is to picking cherries. The latter is purely metaphorical; the former is not.

@alphabet But I can't think of an example where the verb weight-lift is used outside the "working out" context.

@JK2 Yes, but it's restricted, not (say) purely metaphorical, which is why the verb "weightlift" is hardly used at all.

@alphabet There are other compound verbs that can be used literally: spoon-feed. So it's not really about whether a compound verb is only used metaphorically. It's about how often it's being used.

Despite the existence of the verb-derived gerund weightlifting, the "base form" to weightlift doesn't exist (it's not in the full Oxford English Dictionary, Collins, or Merriam-Webster, for example).
So it's a bit pointless asking how to "correctly" write the past participle of the "non-verb". The associated verb phrase (not "phrasal verb") is to lift weights, with past tense He lifted weights.

But if you don't mind using terms that are not (yet?) endorsed by traditional dictionaries, the logical choice must be unhyphenated. Many two-word collocations have undergone an intermediate hyphenated phase before becoming established as single words, which makes the hyphenated forms look old-fashioned today.
Unquestionably to weightlift is a fast-rising neologism. So skip the "dated" orthographical phase.

But hyphenation doesn't necessarily mean undergoing an intermediate hyphenated phase. For example, the verb cherry-pick is much more established than the verb weight-lift and appears in most dictionaries, but its hyphenated version is much more productive. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cherry-picked%2Ccherrypicked&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3 Also, weightlifted has been more productive than weight-lifted from the get-go: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weightlifted%2Cweight-lifted&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3

At the risk of being accused of cherrypicking, consider this chart. I can't help noticing that my Firefox browser underlines the unhyphenated form in my comment (it doesn't like unhyphenated either! :) I think the Internet, computers, and predictive text are behind the meteoric rise of the hyphenated for in the last two decades, not some inexplicable desire on the part of writers to travel back in time!

It's just an -ing noun, not a verb. Try modifying it and you'll see that it can take only adjectives not adverbs, so it cannot be a gerund.

@tchrist: Hmm. Chatgpt says In the sentence "We're going strawberry-picking tomorrow," the word "tomorrow" functions as an adverb. It modifies the verb phrase "going strawberry-picking" by indicating when the action will take place. Strawberries, cherries - it's all the same. Chatgpt also assures me strawberry-picking is a gerund noun there.

@FumbleFingers Unfortunately, modifying the entire predicate is completely different from modifying a single word therein. See also "sentence adverbs".  You cannot have "❌easily cherrypicking", only "easy cherrypicking". If you want an adverb you need a verb: "easily picking cherries". // PLEASE NEVER USE CHATGPT TO SUPPORT ANY ARGUMENT HERE. It is rife with hallucinations. It is not citable. It knows nothing.

@tchrist: You might know more than chatgpt in your "specialist subjects" today, but I think that situation is likely to change in a matter of months rather than years (and the changeover certainly isn't decades in the future! :)

Not that I want to get too bogged down in this, but are you not deliberately cherry picking your supporting arguments here?

@FumbleFingers Deliberately cherry picking is not the same thing as deliberate cherry picking. I'll let you decide which is which on your own, though.

@FumbleFingers Whether to hyphenate or not should be based on the written usage of individual compound words, regardless of whether they're established or not. (Note it's get-go, not getgo.) And one authoritative guide to hyphenation usage is a dictionary, which of course is the outcome of corpus research, a graphic version of which is ngram.

Weightlift, and weight-lift are both in use as verbs informally, and seeing as how they're rather rare and there don't appear to be any authoritative dictionary entries, both forms are on the table as a base for the past participle.
There's at least one convincing published use for weight-lifted as the past participle.

Betty, whose son had weight-lifted with Tom and Dan when the two
of them were doing it twice a day and drinking carrot juice and other
concoctions that were ...(New England Review, Robert Oldshue)

Weightlifted as past participle appears in a few places online.

Mr Williams, 45, who has weightlifted for Wales nine times, has
completed more than 22 sponsored truck and doubledecker bus pulls, two
London Marathons and has even bared all for a charity calendar, but
admits boxing is all new to him. (South Wales Argus)
Magni, a science teacher at Pioneer Valley High School, has
weightlifted for 21 years. (Santa Maria Sun)


Did you ever consider a frame challenge based on a category error instead of digging up exotic rarities? I bet you would have done so, and quickly, had the question asked for the “past participle” of words like all-knowing, bling, cottaging, sibling, middling, pudding, duckling, earthling, fun-loving, fair-seeming, ever-loving, good-looking, snow-bunting (not to mention Kate Bunting :), or for the “present participle” of  words like astroturfed, bigoted, bikinied, crestfallen, firstborn, forlorn, horn-rimmed, double-axled. able-bodied, base-born, store-bought, ill-gotten, unkempt.

@tchrist Though as you know I don't think unidiomatic ventures belong on ELU, I dare say I'd use 'weight-lifted' as Oldshue does if communicating that material. A satisfying workaround is far from easy ('lifted weights with ...' sounds clunky)..

@EdwinAshworth  While any fool can and does zero derive unnilling neologisms that nobody will ever care about, only a genius’s frothing imagine can Jabberwock new lexemes from the unnothed vacuum.

@tchrist The way things are going, we may well read in the not too distant future that someone tiddleywinked their way to an Olympic gold.

@tchrist The infinitival form is pretty common among the gym crowd, so the past participle use doesn't seem much of a stretch. Not everything people write or say has to meet internet search result frequency requirements or be approved by dictionaries. Glad you're having fun writing cutesy comments though.
